# SimpleSAMLphp Partial Single Logout

Tags: php, single-sign-on, saml, saml-2.0, simplesamlphp

I decided to implement `Single Sign On` SSO and `Single Logout` SLO  using `SimpleSAMLPhP` by following https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/ for my project. i was able to implement the `SSO`, but for `SLO`, it was implemented partially

i.e If I logout from `Service Provider` (SP), my `Identity Provider` (IDP) also got logout, but if I logout from my `IDP`, my SP didn't got logout.

If you all need any other information let me know, Thanks for the help

My IDP's  saml20-idp-hosted

```
$metadata['__DYNAMIC:1__'] = array(
    /*
     * The hostname of the server (VHOST) that will use this SAML entity.
     *
     * Can be '__DEFAULT__', to use this entry by default.
     */
    'host' => '__DEFAULT__',

    // X.509 key and certificate. Relative to the cert directory.
    'privatekey' => 'example.org.pem',
    'certificate' => 'example.org.crt',

    /*
     * Authentication source to use. Must be one that is configured in
     * 'config/authsources.php'.
     */
    'auth' => 'example-userpass',
    //'logouttype' => 'iframe',

    'attributes.NameFormat' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri',
    'authproc' => array(
        // Convert LDAP names to oids.
        100 => array('class' => 'core:AttributeMap', 'name2oid'),
    ),


);
```

My IDP's saml20-sp-remote

```
$metadata['http://service.example.com/simplesaml/module.php/saml/sp/metadata.php/default-sp'] = array (
  'SingleLogoutService' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'Binding' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect',
      'Location' => 'http://service.example.com/simplesaml/module.php/saml/sp/saml2-logout.php/default-sp',
    ),
  ),
  'AssertionConsumerService' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'index' => 0,
      'Binding' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST',
      'Location' => 'http://service.example.com/simplesaml/module.php/saml/sp/saml2-acs.php/default-sp',
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'index' => 1,
      'Binding' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:profiles:browser-post',
      'Location' => 'http://service.example.com/simplesaml/module.php/saml/sp/saml1-acs.php/default-sp',
    ),
    2 => 
    array (
      'index' => 2,
      'Binding' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Artifact',
      'Location' => 'http://service.example.com/simplesaml/module.php/saml/sp/saml2-acs.php/default-sp',
    ),
    3 => 
    array (
      'index' => 3,
      'Binding' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:profiles:artifact-01',
      'Location' => 'http://service.example.com/simplesaml/module.php/saml/sp/saml1-acs.php/default-sp/artifact',
    ),
  ),
  'certData' => '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',
);
```

MY SP's saml20-idp-remote

```
$metadata['http://service.ssntpl.com/simplesaml/saml2/idp/metadata.php'] = array (
  'metadata-set' => 'saml20-idp-remote',
  'entityid' => 'http://service.ssntpl.com/simplesaml/saml2/idp/metadata.php',
  'SingleSignOnService' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'Binding' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect',
      'Location' => 'http://service.ssntpl.com/simplesaml/saml2/idp/SSOService.php',
    ),
  ),
  'SingleLogoutService' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'Binding' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect',
      'Location' => 'http://service.ssntpl.com/simplesaml/saml2/idp/SingleLogoutService.php',
    ),
  ),
  'certData' => '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',
  'NameIDFormat' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient',
  );
```

MY SP saml20-idp-hosted

```
$metadata['__DYNAMIC:1__'] = array(
    /*
     * The hostname of the server (VHOST) that will use this SAML entity.
     *
     * Can be '__DEFAULT__', to use this entry by default.
     */
    'host' => '__DEFAULT__',


    // X.509 key and certificate. Relative to the cert directory.
    'privatekey' => 'server.pem',
    'certificate' => 'server.crt',


    /*
     * Authentication source to use. Must be one that is configured in
     * 'config/authsources.php'.
     */
    'auth' => 'example-userpass',
);
```

Comment: Did you get any solution? In my case IdP sends browser to `/simplesaml/module.php/saml/sp/saml2-logout.php/default-sp?SAMLRequest=XXX` but simplesaml redirects to logout URL of IdP with ?SAMLResponse=XXX parameter. A non-simplesaml based SP does not send this redirect.

Comment: @SameerNaik no bro. You can contact the simplesamlphp group on google group. There the dev team of simplesamlphp can help you.